# Is there a way to add i18N to a SLD export from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, internationalization

I have created a SLD from QGIS and I want to add localization (i18n) in GeoServer following the steps from the documentation: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/language.html

However, the format created by QGIS seems to be unsupported by GeoServer in WMS GetLegendGraphic request. I guess it is due to the namespaces of the XML file created:

Is there a way to use this feature in GeoServer with SLD exported by QGIS ?

Versions:
QGIS 3.8 and
GeoServer 2.14.2

Working file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:UserStyle xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <sld:Name>AtlasStyler 1.9</sld:Name>
  <sld:Title/>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <sld:Name>UNIQUE_VALUE_POINT</sld:Name>
    <sld:Title>UniqueValuesPointRuleList</sld:Title>
    <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>
    <sld:Rule>
      <!-- THIS IS THE CORRECT ONE -->
      <sld:Title>Alta: más de 6.8° Richter <Localized lang="en">High: more than 6.8° Richter</Localized> </sld:Title>      
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:Literal>ALL_LABEL_CLASSES_ENABLED</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>ALL_LABEL_CLASSES_ENABLED</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:Not>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>rep_sismo</ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>rep_sismo</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>Rule
              </ogc:Or>
            </ogc:Not>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rep_sismo</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Alta: más de 6.8° Richter</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:And>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1.7976931348623157E308</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <sld:PointSymbolizer>
        <sld:Geometry>
          <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        </sld:Geometry>
        <sld:Graphic>
          <sld:Mark>
            <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#730000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:Mark>
          <sld:Size>
            <ogc:Literal>18.0</ogc:Literal>
          </sld:Size>
        </sld:Graphic>
      </sld:PointSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
```

Not working file (exported by QGIS):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Territorial division</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>u_territorial_divi_frontera_usa_mex_census_bureau_inegi_2018</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>

        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>United States of America</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
 <!-- HERE IS THE ERROR -->
            <se:Title>United States of America
               <Localized lang="en">United States of America</Localized>
               <Localized lang="es">Estados Unidos de América</Localized>
            </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>country_1</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>United States of America</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ca926a</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#404040</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: can you please add the error from the log file?